# how to get rsync to recognise ssh publickey when run from script (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, rsync

Strange issue here.

Running a script calling rsync over ssh throws

> "Permission denied (publickey). rsync: connection unexpectedly closed
>   (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]"

strangely:

1. ssh user@host works, so ssh keys are all set up correctly
2. logging and pasting the command being spawned by the script into the terminal works
3. running whoami from script shows correct user, and environment is passed to spawn instance via process.env
4. running ssh user@host from script does not throw error and returns buffer, so that seems to work
5. running the script (which simply execs the already tested command) throws the above error

   ```
   var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
   spawn('rsync', [
       '-avc',
       '--delete',
       '"'+src+'"' , 
       '--link-dest="'+path.join(dest, folder_name)+'"',
       '"'+path.join(dest, 'latest/')+'"'
       ],{ 
           cwd: process.cwd(),
           env: process.env
   });
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to specify the path to the key

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /home/thisuser/cron/thishost-rsync-key" remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/dir /this/dir/
```

Comment: hi there, that throws a different error: rsync: Failed to exec /usr/local/bin/ssh -i /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: So your key it no accessible... are you sure you have generated one ? usually this a .pub (naming convention not to get it wrong) that we share publicly.

Comment: rsync -avz -e "/usr/local/bin/ssh -i /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa" --delete "user@host:/src/" --link-dest="/link" "/dest" (also tried id_dsa.pub)

Comment: well according to rsync, yea, so i looked into that, but ssh is working fine outside of this one case, i can ssh user@host or just ssh host and the key works... really weird

Comment: My bad this is not the .pub that you want to use here anyway.

Comment: This example works, it may have to many parameter through: https://gist.github.com/3388314

Comment: that works for push using full ssh:// url :D  but it does give a warning: 'Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.' I'm gonna have a play with this and see if i can get it to pull as well

Comment: Oh yeah sorry this is a push only example.

Comment: that's cool! works both ways. removed -t option to get rid of the error